# regex (Regular Expression )for sub string

Tags: java, android, regex

I am having an activity that return string message 
String value of my file id like

`file!^#123456`

I am interesting only the number of that file id i see some regex expression but i did not understand properly.

Answer (score 1):

if I get it right regex for "I am interesting only the number of that file id" will be : `[0-9]+` or with Java Predefined Character Classes; `[\d]+`.

Comment: https://www.debuggex.com/r/A1YEMH-EHyjdeUUM

Comment: https://ideone.com/c3Ty7T

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String str = "file!^#123456";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\D+",""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go at it using substring on it's own:

```
    String s = "file!^#123456";
    System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf("#") + 1, s.length()));
```